# Join table with json column

Tags: php, laravel, mariadb

I want to join my json column with user table, is there a way to reach this using query in mariadb?

[image: doc_table]

[image: user_table]

[image: I want it to be like this]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`JSON_CONTAINS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-contains) do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON 
      JSON_CONTAINS(table1.doc_sharewith, JSON_QUOTE(table2.id))
```

or in Laravel:

```
Table1::join('table2', \DB::raw('JSON_CONTAINS(table1.doc_sharewith, JSON_QUOTE(table2.id))'), '=', 1)
```

Note that such a join will be very slow because it is unable to use indexes so for any kind of efficiency you should switch to a normalised data structure or to a dedicated JSON database like MongoDB